# How do I add a browser to chrome device mode so I can see what my webpage looks like on devices inside various browsers?

Tags: css, google-chrome, pixel, device, viewport

I want to see how my website will look when viewed on various devices (eg. phones). I can use Device Mode in chrome, but the viewport there doesn't include any browser or phone real estate that the phone's browser and footer buttons takes up. Is there a simple way to add this? I thought of somehow using a browser as the device mode target and then I'd just use the browser in the device window to input my site address and see what it would look like in the phone browser but that only gets me the surrounding browser 'frame' and wouldn't show the phone controls that are usually taking up pixels at the bottom of the screen. Is there some kind of overlay that would do this and how would I install it?

Extra credit: I know how to add 'custom' device, but is there an easy 'download and install' way of getting more devices, especially the most popular ones?